# How to improve performance of SELECT query to same tables in Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, linked-server, query-performance

I have a `SELECT` query to a linked server. It looks similar to this

```
SELECT     @Var1 = (SELECT  COL1
                    FROM    [LinkedServer].[dbo].[TableA]
                    WHERE   <Condition1>),
           @Var2 = (SELECT  COL1
                    FROM    [LinkedServer].[dbo].[TableA]
                    WHERE   <Condition2>),
           @Var3 = (SELECT  COL1
                    FROM    [LinkedServer].[dbo].[TableA]
                    WHERE   <Condition3>),
           ...
FROM       [LinkedServer].[dbo].[TableB]
WHERE      <Condition4>
```

So there are multiples `SELECT` statements to the same table in this linked server. Is there a way to improve the performance? Is copying `TableA` to a temp table in local database server a bad idea? Size of `TableA` is large.

[UPDATE1]: Updated my query

```
SELECT      VAR_1, 
            (SELECT  SOL
            FROM     [LinkedServer].[dbo].[TableSol]
            WHERE    COL_1 = [TableA].COL_1
            AND      COL_2 = [TableA].COL_2
            AND      COL_A = [TableA].COL_A) AS VAR_2,
            (SELECT  SOL
            FROM     [LinkedServer].[dbo].[TableSol]
            WHERE    COL_1 = [TableA].COL_3
            AND      COL_2 = [TableA].COL_4
            AND      COL_A = [TableA].COL_A) AS VAR_3,
            (SELECT  SOL
            FROM     [LinkedServer].[dbo].[TableSol]
            WHERE    COL_1 = [TableA].COL_5
            AND      COL_2 = [TableA].COL_6
            AND      COL_A = [TableA].COL_A) AS VAR_4,
FROM        [LinkedServer].[dbo].[TableA]
INNER JOIN  [LinkedServer].[dbo].[TableB] ON [TableA].COL_10 = [TableB].COL_11
```

It took me 15 secs to run the above query. I changed to use crosstab like below:

```
SELECT      VAR_1
            SOL.VAR_2,
            SOL.VAR_3,
            SOL.VAR_4,
FROM        [LinkedServer].[dbo].[TableA]
INNER JOIN  [LinkedServer].[dbo].[TableB] ON [TableA].COL_10 = [TableB].COL_11
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 
                CASE 
                    WHEN COL_1 = [TableA].COL_1 AND COL_2 = [TableA].COL_2 THEN SOL
                    ELSE ''
                END AS VAR_2,
                CASE 
                    WHEN COL_1 = [TableA].COL_3 AND COL_2 = [TableA].COL_4 THEN SOL
                    ELSE ''
                END AS VAR_3,
                CASE 
                    WHEN COL_1 = [TableA].COL_5 AND COL_2 = [TableA].COL_6 THEN SOL
                    ELSE ''
                END AS VAR_4
             FROM    [LinkedServer].[dbo].[TableSol]
             WHERE    COL_A = [TableA].COL_A
            ) AS SOL (VAR_2, VAR_3, VAR_4)
```

But it took me much longer (> 10 mins and I just stop because it did not finish).
Did I miss something?

Comment: Rather than use a 4 part convention to the linked server have you tried using OPENQUERY instead? It should perform a lot better, especially as you are not joining between servers.

Comment: I read `OPENQUERY` does not allow variables. I need some variables to be passed through the query.

Comment: To return data to variables you could just write to a local table, and select into the variables from there.

Answer (score 2):

The query can be rewritten with a crosstab, in order to avoid hitting TableA multiple times:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (col1 int, col2 int);
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (col3 int, col4 int);

INSERT INTO @TableA 
VALUES 
    (1,1),
    (2,2),
    (3,3),
    (4,4);

INSERT INTO @TableB
VALUES 
    (1,1),
    (2,2),
    (3,3),
    (4,4);

DECLARE @Var1 int, @Var2 int, @Var3 int;

SELECT     @Var1 = CA.var1,
           @Var2 = CA.var2,
           @Var3 = CA.var3
FROM @TableB AS TB
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 1 THEN col1 END) AS var1,
              -- ^^ This is <Condition1>
        SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 2 THEN col1 END) AS var2,
              -- ^^ This is <Condition2>
        SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 3 THEN col1 END) AS var3
              -- ^^ This is <Condition3>
    FROM @TableA AS TA
) AS CA(var1, var2, var3)
WHERE TB.col3 > 2 -- <Condition4>

SELECT @Var1, @Var2, @var3
```

This should make it faster. If it doesn't, please post the execution plan, so that we can investigate it further.

Comment: Hi I changed my query, but it even gets longer. I cannot post the execution plan as I do not have enough privilege on the linked server.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the query at the linked server as a pass-through query using the 4-part name notation and `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @var1 int, @var2 int, @var3 int, @var4 int;

EXEC [linkedserver].[databasename].sys.sp_executesql 
    N'
SELECT      @var1 = VAR_1, 
            @var2 = (
            SELECT  SOL
            FROM     [dbo].[TableSol]
            WHERE    COL_1 = [TableA].COL_1
            AND      COL_2 = [TableA].COL_2
            AND      COL_A = [TableA].COL_A),
            @var3 = (
            SELECT  SOL
            FROM     [dbo].[TableSol]
            WHERE    COL_1 = [TableA].COL_3
            AND      COL_2 = [TableA].COL_4
            AND      COL_A = [TableA].COL_A),
            @var4 = (
            SELECT  SOL
            FROM     [dbo].[TableSol]
            WHERE    COL_1 = [TableA].COL_5
            AND      COL_2 = [TableA].COL_6
            AND      COL_A = [TableA].COL_A),
FROM        [dbo].[TableA]
INNER JOIN  [dbo].[TableB] 
    ON [TableA].COL_10 = [TableB].COL_11
    ',
    N'@var1 int OUTPUT, @var2 int OUTPUT, @var3 int OUTPUT, @var4 int OUTPUT',
    @var1 OUTPUT, 
    @var2 OUTPUT,
    @var3 OUTPUT, 
    @var4 OUTPUT;

SELECT @var1, @var2, @var3, @var4;
```

If you don't need to assign to variables, you can use this syntax:

```
EXEC [linkedserver].[databasename].sys.sp_executesql 
    N'
SELECT      VAR_1, 
            (
            SELECT  SOL
            FROM     [dbo].[TableSol]
            WHERE    COL_1 = [TableA].COL_1
            AND      COL_2 = [TableA].COL_2
            AND      COL_A = [TableA].COL_A),
            (
            SELECT  SOL
            FROM     [dbo].[TableSol]
            WHERE    COL_1 = [TableA].COL_3
            AND      COL_2 = [TableA].COL_4
            AND      COL_A = [TableA].COL_A),
            (
            SELECT  SOL
            FROM     [dbo].[TableSol]
            WHERE    COL_1 = [TableA].COL_5
            AND      COL_2 = [TableA].COL_6
            AND      COL_A = [TableA].COL_A),
FROM        [dbo].[TableA]
INNER JOIN  [dbo].[TableB] 
    ON [TableA].COL_10 = [TableB].COL_11
    '
```

Comment: What if the `SELECT` statement returns more than one row? If I do looping by using `CURSOR`, it will hurt the performance as well.

Comment: From your original question, it looked like you needed to return a single row and populate some variables from the results. If that is not the case any more, don't do it.

Comment: From the original question, yes the query was returning a single row. I used a cursor previously to do looping. In my updated query, I removed the cursor at that point to improve the performance.

Comment: Cool. Then don't assign to variables and don't pass them. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ok I just tried this one, but it does not seem to give noticeable improvement. I use a larger dataset, and the time taken for the initial query is 1 mins 47 secs, and using `EXEC [linkedserver].[databasename].sys.sp_executesql` takes 1 mins 45 secs.